# Get the final height of jquery's slideToggle() before it finishes executing - without fixed heights in CSS

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, height, slidetoggle

I need a `div B` on my website to update dynamically according to the run time changing height of another `div A`. `div A` uses the jquery `slideToggle()` [on several divs inside the `div A`], but `div B` should only be changing (at the same time) to match the current height of `div A`. `panel_toggle1` and `panel1` are contained inside `div A`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#panel_toggle1").click(function () {
        $("#panel1").slideToggle("slow", function () {
            var divAheight = $("#divA").height();
            $("#divB").animate({ height: divAheight }, "slow");
        });
    });
});
```

The above code does basely what I wanted, however, due to the `callback()`, it waits for the `slideToggle()` to finish before doing the slide effect on the other div (I was forced to do this because `sliteToggle()` does not spit out the final `height()` of `div A` until it finishes).

Is there a way to do this so that both `div A` and `div B` update smoothly at the same time?
i.e. Is there a way to get the height `slideToggle()` will update `div A` *before* it finishes (so that I can just call `.animate()` on `div B` the same time as on `div A`)?

*Note: I don't use fixed heights for any divs in the CSS, I would like to keep it simple*

**Alternatively**, is there a way I can keep `div B` to match `div A`'s height with just CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to set a fixed target height of your divA, the solution would be trivial, you'd just need to set your animations to run simultaneously, e.g. by setting `queue=false`.

Since it seems like you want to run these animations simultaneously without knowing the resulting height of the original animation, a workaround is to use two animations to acheive the effect:

```
var $divB = $("#divB");
$divB.animate({
   height: '600px' // some arbitrary height approaching target height
}, { duration: 5000 /* longer than the next animation */, queue: false });
$("#panel1").slideToggle({
   duration: 'slow', 
   queue: false,
   complete: function () {
       var divAheight = $("#divA").height();
       // stop the animation and begin another with the correct target height
       $divB.stop().animate({ height: divAheight }, "slow");
   }
});
```

Here, both divs begin to animate at the same time.  When the slideToggle animation completes, the code stops the height animation of divB and begins a new height animation of divB = height of divA.  Kinda hacky, but you have to wait until the first animation completes to get the updated height.

The other option would be to perform a calculation to get the height of the result of the slideToggle and then run simultaneous animations:

```
var newHeight = $("#divA").height() - $("#panel1").height(); 
var $divB = $("#divB");
$divB.animate({
   height: newHeight + 'px'
}, { duration: 'slow', queue: false });
$("#panel1").slideToggle({
   duration: 'slow', 
   queue: false
});
```

Comment: Your first solution sounds great, however it isn't easy to manage with more than 1 `panel1`.

Comment: the second solution works, and I've used a `- $("#panel1").height();` instead, but both `div A` and `div B` tend to alternate after `div B` increases in size. i.e. when `panel1` closes `div A` shrinks but strangely `div B` expands. (I'm totally new to javascript) - I need some sort of flag so that the `- $("#panel1").height();` alternates between `-` and `+` each click!