# html5 tabbed pages does not adjust down page

Tags: html

I am struggling with some HTML5.  I have a page that I want to put a form at the top, followed by a tabbed pages....  I am trying to do a collapsing section which has three
columns followed by the tab.... and I want the collapsing section to expand to take up as much space as it needs....what I am seeing is the tab pages don't move down beyond a set amount ...

So here is an outline of what I am trying to do:

- Collapsing section
- col1              col2           col3
- xxxxx             yyyyyy         zzzz
- xxxxx             yyyyyy         zzzz
- /collapsing section

  ```
      tab1 ,  tab2, tab3 .....
  ```

Here is some example code that shows the problem.... I have noticed that this is happening with all sorts of tabs.... For my "real" page I am using a totally different css , etc.... but this example code shows the same problem....

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org    /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><!--DVID=00014EAC-->
<HTML>
 <head>

 <title>Tabs in HTML with CSS</title>
 <style type="text/css">
 <!--
#tabs {
    border-bottom: .5em solid #0033CC;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#tabs li {
     display:inline;
     border-top: .1em solid #03c;
    border-left: .1em solid #03c;
    border-right: .1em solid #03c;
 }
#tabs li a {
      text-decoration: none;
    padding: 0.25em 1em;
    color: #000;
}
#page1 #tabs li#tab1 a, #page2 #tabs li#tab2 a, #page3 #tabs li#tab3 a, .page4  li#tab4 a {
    padding: 0.25em 1em;
    background-color: #03c;
    color: #fff;
}
  -->

.ScanVINTextBoxStyle3 { width: 180px; }
.divTable     { width: 35%; height:  10%; display: table; }
.divTableRow  { width: 100%; height: 100%; display: table-row;}
.divTableCell { width: 25%;  height: 100%; display: table-cell;}


.cols { width:1020px; }
.ltcol, .ctcol, .rtcol { width:300px; margin:0 10px; padding:10px; }
.ltcol, .ctcol         { float:left; }
.rtcol                 { float:right; }

.layer1
 {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 width: 500px;
 }

.heading
{
 margin: 1px;
 color: #fff;
 padding: 3px 10px;
 cursor: pointer;
 position: relative;
 background-color:#c30;
}

.content
{
 padding: 5px 10px;
 background-color:#fafafa;
}

p
{
 padding: 5px 0;
}
 </style>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
     jQuery(".content").hide();
     //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
     jQuery(".heading").click(function () {
         jQuery(this).next(".content").slideToggle(500);
     });
 });
</script>
</head>

<body id="page2">

    <form>
     <div class="divTable">
            <div class="divTableRow">
                <div class="divTableCell"><label>VIN</label> </div>
                <div class="divTableCell"> <text></text> </div>
                 <div class="divTableCell"> <input type="submit"  value="Display"  />  </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="layer1">
                <p class="heading">Data</p>
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="cols">
                        <div class="ltcol">
                                <div class="divTable">
                                    <div class="divTableRow">
                                         <div class="divTableCell"> <label>Voyage</label> </div>
                                         <div class="divTableCell"> <label>xxxx</label>  </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="divTableRow">
                                         <div class="divTableCell"> <label>Vessel</label> </div>
                                         <div class="divTableCell"> <label>xxxx</label>  </div>
                                         <div class="divTableCell"> <label>yyyy</label>  </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="divTableRow">
                                         <div class="divTableCell"> <label>Vessel</label> </div>
                                         <div class="divTableCell"> <label>xxxx</label>  </div>
                                         <div class="divTableCell"> <label>yyyy</label>  </div>
                                    </div>
                                                   <div class="divTableRow">
                                         <div class="divTableCell"> <label>Vessel</label> </div>
                                         <div class="divTableCell"> <label>xxxx</label>  </div>
                                         <div class="divTableCell"> <label>yyyy</label>  </div>
                                    </div>
                                                   <div class="divTableRow">
                                         <div class="divTableCell"> <label>Vessel</label> </div>
                                         <div class="divTableCell"> <label>xxxx</label>  </div>
                                         <div class="divTableCell"> <label>yyyy</label>  </div>
                                    </div>
                               </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ctcol">
                                center
                        </div>
                        <div class="rtcol">
                            right
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </form>



<ul id="tabs">
<li id="tab1"><a href="ztab1.htm">Tab 1</a></li>
<li id="tab2"><a href="ztab2.htm">Tab 2</a></li>
<li id="tab3"><a href="ztab3.htm">Tab 3</a></li>
<li id="tab4"><a href="ztab4.htm">Tab 4</a></li>
</ul>
<p>The only difference in the HTML code between this page and the other three tabbed pages is that this page has an id on the body tag that names it "page2".</p>
<p><a href="/od/layout/a/aa042307.htm">Return to the Tabbed Navigation Article</a> </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a problem with `slideToggle`, you can't `slideToggle` a height of `auto`. It just not within the functionality of it.

As a result you have to use a work around like the ones found [in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14294258/get-the-final-height-of-jquerys-slidetoggle-before-it-finishes-executing-wi)

I used the first method to fix your problem. [Here's a working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rCpTV/1/)

Updated jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
     jQuery(".content").hide();
     //toggle the componenet with class msg_body
     jQuery(".heading").click(function () {
         $(this).next(".content").animate({
           height: '300px' // some arbitrary height approaching target height
        }, { duration: 700 /* longer than the next animation */, queue: false });
         jQuery(this).next(".content").slideToggle({
             duration: 500,
             queue: false,
             complete: function () {
                 var divAheight = $('.content').height();
                 // stop the animation and begin another with the correct target height
                 $(this).stop().animate({ height: divAheight }, "slow");
             }
         });
     });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks....I was so confused about the cause...and this works great....very appreciated!